# Use wrapper class to handle multiple checkbox fields in a single object

Tags: picklist, inputcheckboxes, view, wrapper-class

I've been handed a task and I don't really know where to start:

I have a set of checkbox fields in one object.

These fields do not work well when I want to create a new View in Salesforce. Each checkbox is its own individual field, and they cannot really be filtered.

However, the checkboxes are grouped by topic (activity, sub-activity, etc). This is because they used to be picklists. The picklists worked normally in the View (Field=activity, filter equals $activitytype) but gave my bosses other problems.

It's been suggested that I wrap the checkboxes in a larger object, which would be the field that the View searched through (and might be useful for other things).

However, it looks like the checkboxes would have to still exist, and clutter up the View fields. The only way to eliminate them from the View would be (I think) to have them not render.

In this case the only way for someone to check or uncheck the checkboxes (which is necessary) would be through the wrapper class object, which I would have to display as a table on the same visualforce page as the checkboxes.

I'm not even sure if I can use a wrapper class to affect a checkbox, so it may be that i'm going down completely the wrong road here.

In short, my question is:
How can I get the View function in Salesforce to treat a bunch of checkboxes as an equivalent picklist, by making the name of that bunch the 'field name' and making each individual checkbox name a filter? Is wrapping even the right way to do this? I just found out about fieldsets, would they be useful?

Any help is appreciated,

Aaron

EDIT: New information:

So, the original functionality looks like this:[image: Original Picklist Functionality]

As you can see, the top picklist field is called 'activity'.

Now, when you go to the 'Create a new View' function, you see this:
[image: Original View Functionality]

It is possible to select 'Activity' and set it to 'includes Employment, Training, etc.' for the new view. This feature is what my bosses are interested in having.

However, they have also asked me to do this:[image: New Checkbox Functionality]

Note that the new table of checkboxes, marked 'Activity' contains the same choices as the old picklist marked 'Activity' (slightly renamed, but that's all).
They like some things about this, but what they didn't think of (and I didn't know) was that the effect this has on the 'Create New View' function.

[image: New Create New View function]

As you can see, the Field Select now includes each individual checkbox as a selectable option. What we want is the old functionality - the ability to choose 'Activity' and filter by which option is selected. We just want to do this with checkboxes instead of picklists.

I hope this clarifies things. If not, please let me know.
Also I apologise for not getting this up sooner - we're doing a software upgrade and yesterday got a bit hairy.
Aaron

Comment: it would probably be helpful if you could describe a bit about the business use case that you're trying to solve with these checkboxes, nee picklists, as it's hard to visualize the problem you're facing. What is the object that is being Viewed, what are some of the fields on it, and what do the checkboxes represent? Do you have a screenshot or a mockup of what it might could/should be when you're done with the implementation?

Comment: I've added some info, with images for clarity. Hope it helps!

Comment: You might want to consider using a combination of jQuery's different menu libraries for this to create an entirely new interface that's more user-friendly for this specific situation. You'd have many more options and possibilities than what you're working with now including flyouts, etc. Ideally it seems like you want this to work like a series of multi-select picklists where some are interrelated and others apparently are not, but still need to be set before a button is pressed.

Comment: That seems like a daunting task, but I appreciate the advice. Thank you crmprogdev.